# How to wire 12 cameras to trigger simultaneously

Tags: gpio

In the documentation of a camera it says:

> "To activate a GPI trigger, momentarily short pin 2 to 1."

But I have 12 cameras and I want to trigger 12 cameras at the same time, how should the circuit be for that? On the pins, there are 3.6 V.

I am really a beginner.

To give more information: this is from the handbook and its a red-one camera.

[image]

Comment: Is this a RED ONE?

Comment: Not knowing how the pins are connected inside the camera (unless there is documentation for this), the cleanest way would be to use 12 reed relays like [this one.](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/9007-05-00/306-1062-ND/301696).  I don't like the idea of connecting the 3.6v rail of all the individual camera together.

Comment: Depending on how 'simultaneously' you want all the cameras to trigger, but if it has to be precise, the relays or reed switches would be too slow and non-synchronized.

Comment: @Naz - FWIW, the linked relay has a operating time of 0.5 ms, so they're pretty damn fast.

Comment: Dejvid_no1 yes it is a red one

Comment: If you have 12 x RED ONE cameras then you pay a competent engineer to design and build you a circuit that works. He will charge you a small fraction of the cost of a single camera.

Comment: Agreed - this is a job that can be done for you with very high quality in about a day. You'll need to source connectors and determine whether you want wireless or wired, do some soldering...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If they're all at 3.6 V**, you should be able to short all pins 2 together. Then short all pins 1 together. Then put one switch that shorts all pins 2 to pins 1. This assumes there's no safety issue with this, and all of the cameras operate at the same ground voltage.

To ensure there isn't some compatibility problem and you don't damage them, I'd wire up a BJT or a MOSFET to each camera. Then send one control signal to all of the BJTs or MOSFETs. If you want to go low-tech or you want isolation between the cameras, you could use 12 relays instead of the BJTs or MOSFETs.

---

EDIT: After reading the manual on it, it looks like they're all battery powered cameras and the GPI is just an input pin to a microcontroller that has a pull-up resistor on it (educated guess). You should be completely safe with my first suggestion, wire all Pins 1 (Gnd) together. Wire all pins 2 together. That will connect all of the pull-ups together. Then use one BJT or MOSFET to connect these two together if you want an electronic signal triggering them all. If you just want a push button switch, you don't need any electronics at all. Just wire them all together as suggested and then add a momentary push switch between the set of Pins 2 and the set of Gnd's (Pins 1).

Comment: Since typical cameras are battery powered, I think he should short all the grounds together.  I don't think it's ok to assume that battery powered devices are at the same ground.  Right?

Comment: @AlcubierreDrive That's likely a good idea. Without further information though about the type of cameras, we really can't determine the best method. Relays would definitely be the safest bet.

Comment: Hey horta, i've edited my post, as you said, you don't know what type of camera it is and additional information?

Comment: @user1767754 Added an edit clarifying that the first solution will work fine.

Comment: Thanks horta, this makes now much more sense, this solution sounds very good. So 90% i couldn't damage the cameras? even if there is no pull-up resistor?

Comment: @user1767754 As long as all the cameras are the same type, they're all expected to be capable of shorting GPI to GND. Connecting two separate battery operated systems together with 1 wire (no closed loop) will not negatively impact anything. Just to be sure, make sure that all of the GPI pins show the same voltage even when not connected.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, use something like [SN74ABT5402](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet2/2/04k683uzgkzl0d058gww86iwh3py.pdf) 12bit buffer, and short all the input pins (as horta suggested) of the buffer, instead of the pins of all cameras? Also, it will ensure synchronicity as opposed to separate relays.

Comment: Can you explain what is the reason why this approach will be more synchronous?

Comment: @boardbite With one signal you can trigger all gates as well. I thought that response delay would be shorter (max propagation delay is less that 9ns). I would expect that the %difference in switching would be less. I do not know anything about these cameras, but if the video is high frame rate and will be used to say calculate 3D rotational motion of an object from different angles while falling, you want your cameras to show a close to real-time synchronicity.

Answer (score 0):

If ground can be commoned you can use 12 switches of your choice.
Relays or MOSFETs or ... .

It is quite likely that a diode to ground will work.
If so you can use a single switch or relay or MOSFET and 12 diodes to GPI pins.
Using a diode is easily trialled and will do no harm*.

If grounds can not be connected then optocouplers or relays will work. 
It is highly likely that optocouplers with bipolar transistor outputs will be OK and this gives you isolation against unforeseen circumstances.

Ask if more detail wanted.

*I'm sure it won't cause harm, BUT this advice is liability freee - I can't afford one Red One, let alone 12.